# Continuous function on $c_{00} $ space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider the space of eventually zero sequences:
$$c_{00} = \left\{ x = (x_{(1)},x_{(2)},\dots,x_{(k)},\dots)\in\ell^\infty \,\middle|\, \exists k_0 \text{ such that $x_{(k)}=0$ for $k>k_0$}\right\}$$ and ${f}: {c}_{00} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,$\mathrm{f}(\mathrm{x})=\sum_{\mathrm{k}=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\mathrm{k}} \mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{k}} \quad\left(\mathrm{x}=\left\{\mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{k}}\right\} \in {c}_{\mathrm{00}}\right)$

> Is $f$ continuous with norm $\|\mathbf{x}\|_{\infty}=\sup _{\mathbf{k} \in \mathbb{N}}\left|\mathbf{x}_{\mathbf{k}}\right| $ and
> $\|\mathbf{x}\|_{\mathbf{2}}=\left(\sum_{\mathbf{k}=1}^{\infty}\left|\mathbf{x}_{\mathbf{k}}\right|^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} ، \mathbf{x}=\left\{\mathbf{x}_{\mathbf{k}}\right\} \in {c}_{00}$

Let For every $n$, $x_n=(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{n\mathrm{\ times}},0,\ldots)\in c_{00}$, $\Vert x_n\Vert=1$ so $x_n$ is bounded,  (in the sup norm), but the sequence $f( x_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k$ is unbounded. How we can solve second question ?

Comment: Is your second question $\|\mathbf{x}\|_{\mathbf{2}}=\left(\sum_{\mathbf{k}=1}^{\infty}\left|\mathbf{x}_{\mathbf{k}}\right|^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \mathbf{x}=\left\{\mathbf{x}_{\mathbf{k}}\right\} \in {c}_{00}$? Not sure what you are writing, $\|x\|_2$ is a number and $\{x_k\}$ is an element in the space, they cannot be equal.

Comment: the \cdot I think should be a full stop or question mark and then there is a second sentence saying what x is. @ArcticChar (I’m not OP)

Comment: Ok, so it seems the second is whether $f$ is continuous with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$?  @CalvinKhor

Comment: Yeah, that was what I meant to say but was multitasking (sorry)

Comment: For the second question, use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @DanielFischer . I can't proof $f$ is continuous with Cauchy-Schwarz .

Comment: How did you try? It should drop out of Cauchy-Schwarz immediately.